# Trailing char < > at index 119 C:\path\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\fef42996298a890d33d82d17f7cb2b2f\jetified-httpcore-4.3.2

Tags: android, http, gradle, androidx, android-studio-3.0

I am getting Trailing char < > error while run app in debug mode I have recently convert my project to Androidx and api level 29 after this change I am getting this issue. I found [[java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Trailing char < > at index 10: res/raw/?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57255120/java-nio-file-invalidpathexception-trailing-char-at-index-10-res-raw][1])
 this when I google it but I am not using DexGuard. Can anyone help? thanks